# Ms-Access: any need to have a low size for variable-length text fields

Tags: database-design, ms-access, field

In an Ms-Access MDB, will it save disk space to limit the size of variable-length text fields?

eg. If I have a variable-length `Text` field of size `20` and all the actual values of the field are under `10` characters, am I wasting space?

**Would it be better to set the size of the field to `10`, or does it not make any difference?**

Comment: It's not clear if you actually have Access or are just using an MDB file, but if you have Access, I strongly suggest you avail yourself of this handy little thing called a HELP FILE. You might be surprised what you could learn by looking there.

Comment: @David: What difference does it make? The question would apply to both scenarios. And I don't think this issue would be covered in the Help file.

Comment: Have you looked at the help file yourself? If not, have a look and then get back to us.

Comment: I don't see how the question can be answered. What defines "a good idea?" What are your benchmarks for determining if it's helpful/useful, etc.? It's just not a question well-worded enough for a bounty to be helpful, seems to me.

Comment: @David: the question is simply whether it is advisable to reduce the size of variable-length Text field in an MDB.  A good answer would cover all factors that might come into play.

Comment: Perhaps you should revise the question to reflect that. Of course, how whoever set the bounty is going to know that all the factors have been covered, I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *If I have a variable-length Text field of size 20 and all the actual values of the field are under 10 characters, am I wasting space?*

No.

> *Would it be better to set the size of the field to 10, or does it not make any difference?*

It would be better to set 10 as the field size limit if values longer than 10 characters are unacceptable.  If it's OK for a user to enter values between 11 and 20 characters, leave the limit at 20.  The disk space use is a non-issue in this situation.

Comment: Even if the field is part of a PK ? Wouldn't there be a performance and size impact in that case ?

Comment: I mean: Table Customers has a primary key = CustId Text(50). The CustID is never larger than 10 char. Will the db be faster and smaller by setting the CustId field as Text(10) ?

Comment: @iDevlop I doubt it would make a difference for the index size because I don't think the index "pads" field values up to the allowable field width.  I don't know about the performance impact.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not explicitly stated, I think you're asking is there a difference regarding data storage with the limit on variable length strings: There will be no difference using larger or smaller limits. From MSDN, discussing the TEXT data types for JET (The db engine in Access)

> In general, text fields can be up to 255 characters, 
>   [...] In addition, unused portions of text fields are not reserved in
>   memory.

- [Intermediate, Microsoft JET, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The fields are stored as variable length, and thus setting the size as 255, or 10 will not reduce or change the size of the data file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a legacy property from back when memory was expensive.

You could use it as a method of data validation, i.e. if the field holds phone numbers, then giving a length of 10 will prevent invalid and international phone numbers from being entered.

Comment: wouldn't the UI be validating input?

Comment: While one would be wise to avail oneself of whatever tools the UI provides for validating user input, the database engine itself should enforce as much as possible the entry of valid data. Choosing field length is one of the engine-level tools for doing so.

Comment: @David: the UI should have validated any input before it gets to the DB

Comment: Thinking that there's no need to limit the size of the column, as your answer seems to imply, relates to another question: which comes first, the database or the application?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305958/database-designing-an-art-or-headache-managing-relationships

Comment: Yes, the UI should validate all input before it reaches the database. But the database should also have validation rules and indexes that prevent invalid data. You don't know that all data entry/editing will go through the application you've created, and you can't guarantee that mistakes won't be made in the UI validation, or errors introduced in some other way. You need both belt and suspenders or you're application is weak.

Answer (score -4):

The length of the field should be chosen appropriately because it has an effect on index performance and storage because longer values make for more data pages. Of course, if the data is real, i.e., the real values need to be that long, you need it. So, if you have a 50-character field and the longest value is 10 characters, the index won't take up any more space than if the field were 10 characters.

But choosing an appropriate limit helps with designing forms and reports -- if you make the field too long, you may end up with outlier records that don't display/print properly. On the other hand, you don't want it to be too short so that users can't fit normal data in it. Field length is the most basic form of data validation, because you are deciding what the range of appropriate values is for that field.

My basic principle is that I pick the shortest possible field length for data that has a regular format (even if it has occasional exceptions), but am generous with fields that do not.

Comment: please elaborate on how it affects storage.

Comment: Index storage specifically: "Wider" indexes take up more data pages and thus become fragmented more quickly, thus reducing performance. Narrower indexes are quicker to search because it's less data.

Comment: any reference? It seems strange that index space is related to the column definition, and not to the column actual usage.

Comment: You're right, @pascal. You could define a 100-character column with an index, but if the max length was 10, the index likely wouldn't take any more space than if your column was set to 10. It would not surprise me, however, if there were not performance issues associated with having an index on a column with so much potential slack space, but I have no documentation on that, just a gut sense from working with Jet all these years. Like strong data typing, it just seems like good design to me.